# Migrate data from Cassandra cluster to single machine

Tags: cassandra

[image: cluster data size] I have a cassandra cluster(four nodes) on four machines with data size of  745.54 GiB  ,670.79 GiB  ,695.65 GiB  ,634.43 GiB of each node.I need to migrate all the data to single machine with single node .I have all keyspaces with replication factor of 3 and i need to change the replication factor as 1.I didn't find any solution anywhere, Somebody tell me how to migrate this cluster to single machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a snapshot:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSnapShot.html

For example a single table snapshot:

```
nodetool snapshot --table cyclist_name cycling
```

The restore process is documented here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html

Comment: I'd like to add that you need to take this snapshot on all four nodes to include all of your data (2 nodes if you are sure that all of your data has replication 3). Each snapshot then needs to be run through sstableloader to the single node.